# LTspice - using save/load bias with a parameter sweep

Tags: ltspice

I have a circuit which has some hard time converging in a DC simulation.
The circuit does converge nicely in a transient simulation when skipping initial condition calculation.

Therefore, I've ran the transient simulation to get the operating point and saved it with the .savebias statement.
Afterward I load the operating point in the next simulations with the .loadbias statement.

It all works fine and well, until I add a parameter sweep (.step param) in which case the .savebias statement only saves the last sweep value.

Does a solution for this exists ? How can I save the operating point for each value of the swept param separately and load separately ?

I've tried to save the file with the swept parameter value in the file name but to no avail (.savebias tran_bias{stp}.txt).

**EDIT:**
I have managed to save the operating point (rather manually but it's ok for now since I only have 4 values in the sweep) using the undocumented "step" parameter for .savebias

```
.savebias transient_bias_250R.txt internal time = 500u step=0
.savebias transient_bias_500R.txt internal time = 500u step=1
.savebias transient_bias_1k.txt internal time = 500u step=2
.savebias transient_bias_2k.txt internal time = 500u step=3
```

The question of how I can load the corresponding file to the corresponding sweep with .loadbias remains.

Comment: Glad that it worked out. You should post this as an answer and select it, so that future searches for this kind of problem will find the answer easier.

Comment: It's a partial solution though. Maybe someone can figure out how to load the operating point in swept simulations.